# Pad a number with starting zero in .Net

Tags: .net, string, formatting, padding

I have a requirement to pad all single digits numbers with a starting zero. 
Can some one please suggest the best method? (ex 1 -> 01, 2 -> 02, etc)

Comment: How are you outputting these?  If you're, for example, binding them to a control in ASP.NET, there's probably an easier way to apply the format string as you bind them.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'd call [.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_ToString_System_String_) on the numbers, providing a [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types#FormatStrings) which requires two digits, as below:

```
int number = 1;
string paddedNumber = number.ToString("00");
```

If it's part of a larger string, you can use the format string within a placeholder:

```
string result = string.Format("{0:00} minutes remaining", number);
```

Answer (score 80):

```
number.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
```

Comment: Upvoted because this solution is self-documenting -- clearer in its intent than a format provider ("00").

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're just outputing these values, not storing them

```
int number = 1;
Console.Writeline("{0:00}", number);
```

Here's a [useful resource](http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/) for all formats supported by .Net.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna add this option as an answer since I don't see it here and it can be useful as an alternative.

In VB.NET:

```
''2 zeroes left pad
Dim num As Integer = 1
Dim numStr2ch As String = Strings.Right("00" & num.ToString(), 2)

''4 zeroes left pad
Dim numStr4ch As String = Strings.Right("0000" & num.ToString(), 4)

''6 zeroes left pad
Dim numStr6ch As String = Strings.Right("000000" & num.ToString(), 6)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# In PowerShell:

$year = 2013
$month = 5
$day = 8

[string] $datestamp = [string]::Format("{0:d4}{1:d2}{2:d2}", $year, $month, $day)
Write-Host "Hurray, hurray, it's $datestamp!"
```

Comment: The codder asked for vb.net why give him powershell